# How to combine unions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have

```
type a = { a: "hi", b: number }
type b = { a: "bye", b: number }
```

I want somehow to do :

```
type c = a + b // there's nothing called "+"
```

and get `c` inferred as

```
type c = { a: "hi" | "bye", b: number };
```

I tried doing:

```
import { UnionToIntersection } from 'utility-types'

type a = { a: "hi", b: number }
type b = { a: "bye", b: number }
type c = UnionToIntersection<a | b> // never
```

But `c` is being inferred as `never`.

---

edit*

If you don't mind, here's another use case

```
type o = {
  type: "bar";
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
} | {
  type: "baz";
  foo: string;
  baz: boolean;
}
```

I want to somehow convert this type into the following type:

```
type: "bar" | "baz"  ;
foo: string;
bar?: number;
baz?: boolean;
```

Comment: ① This isn't [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), or at least that's a misleading term.  Could you [edit] to use a less confusing term?  Maybe "merge" or "combine" or something?  ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpz3pw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, actually my question is wrong I meant to ask about something else. OK. and anyway I'll post a newer question

Comment: @jcalz,  actually the playground link you posted is intresting. what's the difference between this approach, and Daniel's answer approach?

Comment: if you don't mind I edited my question to include a more specific use case

Comment: I don't "mind" exactly, but I am a bit concerned that the scope of the question will continue to creep.  Still, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3KM3m) is what one might do here. Shall I write that up as an answer or am I missing something about your needs?

Comment: @jcalz, yes [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3KM3m) is good. I solves the problem

Comment: @jcalz Is the `Merge` type helper [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpz3pw) the same as The [Prettify Helper](https://www.totaltypescript.com/concepts/the-prettify-helper)?

Comment: No, have you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is very close to an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) operation; if you have a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `A | B` and access its properties, each of the properties will automatically become unions.  If that's all you wanted then you could just use the union as-is, or if you want, write a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to collapse the union into a single object type.

The only wrinkle here is you want properties that only appear in some of the union members to be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) in the combined type, whereas a union will tend to just omit such properties.  So the first thing we should do is convert each member of the union into a new type with optional properties of type [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) for any property that isn't defined in that member.  That is, we want to turn `{a: 0, b: 1} | {b: 2, c: 3}` into something like `{a: 0, b: 1, c?: never} | {a?: never, b: 2, c: 3}`.  That will then combine to form `{a?: 0, b: 1 | 2, c?: 3}` as desired when merged.

Putting that together looks like this:

```
type _Combine<T, K extends PropertyKey = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never> =
    T extends unknown ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type Combine<T> = { [K in keyof _Combine<T>]: _Combine<T>[K] }
```

Here `_Combine<T>` is a helper type that uses [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to split `T` into union members and perform operations on them.  The first is the [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for `K` which collects all the keys of the members of `T` (`T extends unknown ? keyof T : never`), and the second is where we [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) each member of `T` with an object with optional keys of type `never` for every key in `K` which isn't part of that member of `T`.

And then `Combine<T>` is an identity mapped type over `_Combine<T>` which collapses ugly things like `({a: 0, b: 1) & Partial<Record<"c", never>>) | ({b: 2, c: 3} & Partial<Record<"a", never>>)` to the desired `{a?: 0, b: 1 | 2, c?: 3}`.

---

Let's test it out on your example:

```
type O = {
    type: "bar";
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
} | {
    type: "baz";
    foo: string;
    baz: boolean;
}

type Z = Combine<O>;
/* type Z = {
    type: "bar" | "baz";
    foo: string;
    bar?: number | undefined;
    baz?: boolean | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good.  The `type` and `foo` properties are required, since they exist in all members of `O`, while the `bar` and `baz` properties are optional, since they are missing from at least one member of `O`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAFwngDgpgBA+gYQPYFsBGBLAdlAPAFQBoYBpGKADxCiwBMBnGABQCcloXwSowYBeGPnJUaDGAFcsAayxIA7lhgB+GFJ5IAZoJgAuGDgBuUFgD5+wGJe2VqdRpJnzFKoQDJmAQ04YPAG1wASlAAxkgstLgAohTBvuK0eCTEamCagibEhsYmZnpZLADcoJCwyOjYePhmAgDeMADaZNiq6lqIqJg4BCYAunrt5V1VjT0wAL7AxdAwAPL8MDUWVuDQegBEaF5rRVYwGkhIevQgLNgA5jtWmyx54ujGRWMwAD4LS5YrUOubAF7b73sDkcTudLpZfno0AdfFAPFhHpNPjAAFrzMqdPAzExFAD0ACoYEjUbUAZ9vlsXjANh4-mDAYcYMdTlgLgDrkpbvcWJTJAkNBVaHTfhyYFCkDC4Ty6FB+ThBcAnnicUA)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```typescript
type c = a | b;
```

Because `b` is a common property it will be merged without changes, and `a` will be merged as `"hi" | "bye"`.

This could be shown by some IDEs as `{ a: "hi", b: number } | { a: "bye", b: number }` instead of `{ a: "hi" | "bye", b: number }` but it's functionally identical.

See this working example:
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDesBcUBEALAlhgNFAEboB2ArgLZEQBOUAvgFCiTELJqZEgQHFkqNesxbhoAYw5wAPsQDcTJgBsIwKMAgBnYOimIkMdBh59CJKAFZmUKEA)

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind I just updated my question and added a newer example

Comment: It is not merging the properties. Autocomplete is simply showing the type for that property; because the type is a union, that type is equivalent to `a['a'] | b['a']`: if the object is of type `a`, the property will be `"hi"`; if it is of type `b`, the property will be `"bye"`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes. for this case, `test.a` can only be `"hi"` or `"bye"`. Which is correct for the first example in the question, but it does not solve the second example in the question (which is a newer one I added before this answer was posted)

Comment: Yes, because this is not merging properties, it is simply creating a union that may have the appearance of the properties having been merged. The difference will show when you try and do anything slightly advanced, such as accidentally discriminating the type or using it as a generic parameter (in which case union distribution might come into play).

Comment: For example, these two types are very different: `{ a: "hi" | "bye", b: string | number }` and `{ a: "hi", b: string } | { a: "bye", b: number }`. The first will behave as expected, while the second... will sometimes. `if (obj.a === "hi") { /* With the first one, obj.b is string | number; with the second, it is string */ }`

Comment: @DarrylNoakes, I made a new question regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841989/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-doing-unions)