# What's the difference between these two ways of doing unions?

Tags: typescript

What is the difference between the `X` and `Y` types in the following examples?

```
type X = {
    a: "hi" | "bye";
    b: number;
}

type Y = { a: "hi", b: number } | { a: "bye", b: number }
```

I got `X` by doing:

```
type A = { a: "hi", b: number }
type B = { a: "bye", b: number }
type C =  A | B

type MergeUnion<T> = { [K in ({} & keyof T)]: T[K] };


type X = MergeUnion<C>
```

And I got `Y` by simply doing:

```
type Y = a | b;
```

Are there any differences between the two approaches?

This question is a branch for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77841758/how-to-combine-unions-in-typescript) question that lead to here.

Comment: `X` is a single object type whose properties are unions, whereas `Y` is a union of object types whose properties are not unions.  Unions have special behaviors, such as [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments), leading to [this difference of behavior](https://tsplay.dev/wXgJOW).  The types are related but not identical.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I could write an answer (or find a duplicate target); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: `Y` will be distributed in some cases (see [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)), meaning that the union is effectively "looped over" member by member; it behaves as separate object types for a while. Also, it can be discriminated, which may be unexpected if you were simply trying to check a property for a certain value: `if (obj.a === "hi") { /* With the first one, obj.b is string | number; with the second, it is string */ }`

Comment: yes now I see it clearly *thanks *